# How to localize a date field in a django generic view

Tags: python, django, localization, django-generic-views

I am very new to Python and Django and started to learn it just recently. So, I wanted to create a form with Django using generic views, here CreateView.

In my form I have a date field and this only works with entries like "01/01/1970". But for my settings I need the validation to understand "01.01.1970" to be the same date (so, basically `%D.%M.%Y` or something similar).

I found instructions how to use this with a self built form, but I do not understand how to use parameters like `localize=True` in combination with a generic view yet. Because I do not have a template which lists all of the fields separately. This is done automatically by a loop, if I understood that correctly.

Edit: My question is how I can get the date validator to accept the aformentioned date format with dots instead of slashes.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You want confirmation that "This is done automatically by a loop, if I understood that correctly." , right?

Comment: The sentence about the loop just meant that I thought that the generic class-based view got all of the fields of a model and rendered them into a template via some built-in loop function.

Comment: Thanks. Please edit your question if you think I edited it wrong.